# Return all SSRS reports in a folder with the data source name and ConnectString

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

This what I have so far. However, I want to list every report to it's connection string. I don't see a unique identifier in the `GetDataSourceContents()` method to join the report and data source lists.

```
$ReportServerUri = "YOUR_SERVER";
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "SSRS" 
$rs.Url = "YOUR_SERVER"
$rs.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials; 

$BICItems = $rs.ListChildren("/", $true);
$BICFolders = $BICItems | Where { $_.TypeName -eq "Folder"}
$BICDataSources = $BICItems | Where {$_.typename -eq "DataSource"}
$BICDataSourceFolders = $BICFolders | Where {$_.path -like "*Data Source*"}
$BICReports = $BICItems | Where {$_.typename -eq "Report"}

foreach ($DataSource in $BICDataSources)
{
   $BICDataSourceContents = $rs.GetDataSourceContents($DataSource.Path)

   $MyConnectStrings = $BICDataSourceContents | Where {$_.ConnectString -like "*MY_CONNECT_STRING*"} 

   $MyConnectStrings
}
```

Comment: My apologies. I've added my code so far, and thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I tried to answer as best I could. You might find it a little verbose. If you have _any_ interest I could put up more on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see a unique identifier in the GetDataSourceContents method to join the report and data source lists.

Nope. Neither do I. However when were are querying for those details we already know something unique enough. The path to the datasource itself. This is also what a report would be using so that should be a good connector.

There is a series of functions that I made to serve this purpose. `Find-SSRSEntities`, `Get-SSRSReportDataSources` and `Get-SSRSDatasourceDetails` are what I will try and showcase here. The last one I just made since I had no reason for those details but it was easy enough to integrate into my module.

### Find-SSRSEntities

Return items from a SSRS connection. Supports loads of filtering options.

```
function Find-SSRSEntities{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("Proxy")]
        [Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol]$ReportService,

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [string]$SearchPath="/",

        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [ValidateSet("All", "Folder", "Report", "Resource", "LinkedReport", "DataSource", "Model")]
        [Alias("Type")]
        [String]$EntityType = "All",

        [Parameter(Position=3)]
        [String]$Match,

        [Parameter(Position=4)]
        [Switch]$Partial=$false
    )
    # Get all of the catalog items that match the criteria passed
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.listchildren.aspx
    $recursive = $true
    $catalogItems = $ReportService.ListChildren($SearchPath,$recursive)
    Write-Verbose "$($catalogItems.Count) item(s) located in the root path $SearchPath"

    # Limit the results to the catalog types requested
    if($EntityType -ne "All"){$catalogItems = $catalogItems | Where-Object{$_.Type -eq $EntityType}}
    Write-Verbose "$($catalogItems.Count) item(s) found matching the type $EntityType"

    # Set the match string based on parameters
    if(-not $Partial.isPresent -and $Match){$Match = "^$Match$"}
    Write-Verbose "Returning all items matching: '$Match'"

    # If the regex is an empty string all object will be returned.
    return $catalogItems | Where-Object{$_.Name -match $Match}
}
```

### Get-SSRSReportDataSources

When given a valid report path it will return all associated datasources of that report.

```
function Get-SSRSReportDataSources{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("Proxy","SSRSService")]
        [Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol]$ReportService,

        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [string]$ReportPath
    )

    # Test the report path to be sure it is for a valid report
    if(Test-SSRSPath -ReportService $ReportService -EntityPath $ReportPath -EntityType Report){
        $ReportService.GetItemDataSources($reportPath) | ForEach-Object{
            [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                ReportPath = $reportPath
                DataSourceName = $_.name
                Reference = $_.item.reference
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Error "$ReportPath is not a valid report path"
    }
}
```

### Get-SSRSDatasourceDetails

When given a valid datasource path it will return all detail of that datasource. Also attaches an extra path property.

```
function Get-SSRSDatasourceDetails{
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias("Proxy")]
        [Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol]$ReportService,

        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [string]$EntityPath
    )

    process{
        # Split the path into its folder and entity parts
        $SearchPath = Split-SSRSPath $EntityPath -Parent
        $EntityName = Split-Path $EntityPath -Leaf

        # Verify the path provided is to a valid datasource
        if((Find-SSRSEntities -ReportService $ReportService -SearchPath $SearchPath -EntityType DataSource -Match $EntityName -Partial:$false) -as [boolean]){
            Add-Member -InputObject ($ReportService.GetDataSourceContents($EntityPath)) -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $EntityPath -PassThru
        } else {
            Write-Warning "Could not find a datasource at path: $EntityPath"
        }
    }
}
```

So armed with those lets match up all reports in a folder to their datasource connection strings. I would note that all of these functions rely on a active connection to work. Something like this

```
$ssrsservice = Connect-SSRSService "http://ssrsreports/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx" -Credential $credentials
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("*SSRS*:ReportService",$ssrsservice)
```

That will automatically apply the populated `-ReportService $ssrsservice` to all the SSRS functions I made below.

Else you could just add something like `Find-SSRSEntities -ReportService $rs` to the code below and it would work.

```
# Lets get all of the Marketing Datasources
$datasources = Find-SSRSEntities -SearchPath "/data sources/marketing" -EntityType DataSource | Get-SSRSDatasourceDetails

# Now gather all of their reports
Find-SSRSEntities -SearchPath "/Marketing" -EntityType Report | 
    # Get the report datasources
    Get-SSRSReportDataSources | ForEach-Object{
        # Attach the connection strings to each object 
        $reportDataSourceDetail = $_
        # Filter the datasource for the individual datasource mapping of this report
        $matchingDatasource = $datasources | Where-Object{$_.path -eq $reportDataSourceDetail.Reference}
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ConnectionString -Value $matchingDatasource.ConnectString -PassThru
}
```

This would net me results that look like this:

```
ReportPath       : /Marketing/OandD Class Summary By Month
DataSourceName   : Marketing
Reference        : /Data Sources/Marketing/Marketing
ConnectionString : Data Source=SQL08R2VM; Initial Catalog=Marketing;

ReportPath       : /Marketing/OandD Class YTD Summary
DataSourceName   : Marketing
Reference        : /Data Sources/Marketing/Marketing
ConnectionString : Data Source=SQL08R2VM; Initial Catalog=Marketing;
```

These, and other functions, suite me just fine. I have not really had anyone else using them so you might have issues that I have never encountered. Works fine connecting to my SSRS 2008R2 server using PowerShell v5

Comment: I'm going to test these asap, but this logic is EXACTLY hoping to accomplish. Honestly, I was wearied by your grammar edits, but I have much to learn. Thanks so much Matt.

Comment: My grammar is not the best. My motivation for edits like that is to try and remove reasons for questions to get downvotes /close votes when they are actually good questions. FYI I add a bit to my answer since I forgot to show how my functions actually use the WebProxy.

Comment: Matt, I'm unable to implement this code. I've had different errors, and without listing them all, I just wanted to let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry that it was not turn key. If you want me to help you i would obviously need some of the errors to work with. Comments are hard for this sort of thing so we can always start a [chat] if that helps

Comment: That would be great. I'm leaving for the day, but can pick it up tomorrow. One thing was this, what value is it looking for here?   ---------    "cmdlet Find-SSRSEntities at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ReportService:" --------- I've tried several inputs.

Comment: My last edit was trying to prevent you from running into that. All of my functions here use `-ReportService`. I have a default parameter value set that takes care of that for me. You could do that like in my answer or you can just supply it. In your case based on your above code it would be: `-ReportService $rs`; add that to my code above and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a T-SQL statement that will return the data source name, path & connection string with the report name and path.

```
;WITH 
XMLNAMESPACES  -- XML namespace def must be the first in with clause. 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource' 
    ,'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' 
    AS rd
) 
, 
shared_datasource 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
          DsnSharedName = sds.[Name]
        , DsnPath = sds.[Path] 
        , DEF = CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), content)) 
    FROM 
        dbo.[Catalog] AS sds 
    WHERE sds.[Type] = 5) --> 5 = Shared Datasource 
, 
data_source_name (DsnPath, DsnSharedName, DsnConnString)
AS
(
    SELECT 
          cn.DsnPath
        , cn.DsnSharedName 
        , cn.DsnConnString 
    FROM 
        (SELECT
              sd.DsnPath
            , sd.DsnSharedName 
            , DsnConnString = dsn.value('ConnectString[1]', 'varchar(150)')
        FROM 
            shared_datasource AS sd 
            CROSS APPLY sd.DEF.nodes('/DataSourceDefinition') AS R(dsn) 
        ) AS cn 
)
SELECT 
      DataSourceName = lk.[Name]
    , dsn.DsnPath
    , dsn.DsnConnString
    , ReportName = c.[Name]
    , ReportFolder = c.[Path]
FROM 
    dbo.[Catalog] c
    INNER JOIN dbo.DataSource ds ON c.ItemID = ds.ItemID
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Catalog] lk ON ds.Link = lk.ItemID
    INNER JOIN data_source_name dsn ON dsn.DsnSharedName = lk.[Name]
WHERE 
    c.[Type] = 2  --> 2 = Reports
    --AND dsn.DsnConnString LIKE '%Initial Catalog%=%DatabaseNameHere%'
```

Then you can run the T-SQL script file in powershell with this. [original post](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-to-Run-d3fefe90/view/Reviews)

```
<# Function to Check whether Server is Ping Status of the Server #>
Function Check-Ping()
{
    param
    (
         [string]$HostName
    )
    $PingStatus=Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address='$HostName'"
    Return $PingStatus
}


<# Function to Check Instance name Present in the Server #>
Function Get-SQLInstances()
{
    param
    (
     [string]$SQLServerName
    )
    $Status=Check-Ping($SQLServerName)
    if($Status.StatusCode -ne 0)
    {
        Return "The Server Is Not Reachable"
    }
    elseif($Status.StatusCode -eq 0)
    {
        $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $SQLServerName)
        $RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server")
        $Instances=$regKey.GetValue("installedinstances")
        Return $Instances        
     }
}


<# Function To Run TSQL and Return Results within HTML Table Tag #>
Function Run-TSQL()
{
Param
(
  [string]$MachineName,
  [string]$TSQLfilePath

)
    $Assembly=[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") 
    $Instances=Get-SQLInstances($MachineName)  
    $TSQL=Get-Content $TSQLfilePath
    foreach($Instance in $Instances)
    {
        $SQLServiceStatus=Get-Service -ComputerName $MachineName | Where-Object {$_.displayname -like "SQL Server ("+$Instance+")"}
        if($SQLServiceStatus.Status -eq "Running")
        {
            if($Instance -eq "MSSQLSERVER")
            {
                $SQLServer=$MachineName
            }
            Else
            {
                $SQLServer=$MachineName+"\"+$Instance
            }
            $SQLServerObject = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SQLServer)
            $DatabaseObject = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
            $DatabaseObject = $SQLServerObject.Databases.Item("Master")##The TSQL Script Runs in Master Database
            $OutPutDataSet = $DatabaseObject.ExecuteWithResults($TSQL)
            for($t=0;$t -lt $OutPutDataSet.Tables.Count;$t++)
            {
                $OutString+="<Table Border=2>"
                $OutString+="<Tr>"
                foreach($Column in $OutPutDataSet.Tables[$t].Columns) 
                { 
                    $OutString+="<Th>"
                    $OutString+=$Column.ColumnName
                    $OutString+="</Th>"
                }     
                $OutString+="</Tr>"                   
                for($i=0;$i -lt $OutPutDataSet.Tables[$t].Rows.Count;$i++)
                {
                    $OutString+="<Tr>"
                    for($j=0;$j -lt $OutPutDataSet.Tables[$t].Columns.Count;$j++)
                    {

                        $OutString+="<Td>"                               
                        $OutString+=$($OutPutDataSet.Tables[$t].Rows[$i][$j])
                        $OutString+="</Td>"
                    }
                    $OutString+="</Tr>"                
                }
                $OutString+="</Table>"
                $OutString+="</Br>"
                $OutString+="</Br>"
            }
        }
    }
Return $OutString
}

<# Function To Add Table Tag to with In HTML tags 
Modify Title and Subject as Per yoru Requirement
#>
Function Get-HTMLOut()
{
Param
(
[String]$InputFile,
[String]$OutputFile,
[String]$TSQL
)

$Out+="<Html>"
$Out+="<Title>Run TSQL and Return HTML FIle</Title>" ## Modify 'TiTle' Tag as per your Required
$Out+="<Head><style>body {background-color:lightgray} H3{color:blue}H1{color:green}table, td, th {border: 1px solid green;}th {background-color: green;color: white;}</style></Head>" ## Modify 'Head' Tag as per your Required
$Out+="<Body><H1 Align='Center'>Run TSQL and Return HTML File</H1></Br></Br>" ## Modify 'Body' Tag as per your Required
ForEach($ServerName in Get-Content $InputFile)
{
    $Out+="<H3 align='center'>--------------$ServerName--------------</H3>" ## Modify 'header Text' Tag as per your Required
    $Out+="</Br>"   
    $Out+=Run-TSQL -MachineName $ServerName -TSQLfilePath $TSQL

}
$Out+="</Body></Html>"
Set-Content -Value $Out -Path $OutputFile
}

<# Call Get-HTMLOut Function
It Accepts 3 parameter
a. -InputFile (.txt file each server in a List withOut Instance Name)
b. -OutputFile (.Html File to which Output need to be sent)
c. -TSQL (.sql file which Contains the Script to Run)
#>
Get-HTMLOut -InputFile ".\Servers.txt" -OutputFile .\Status.Html -TSQL '.\TSQL Script.sql'
```

Comment: I'd prefer to pull from the database, but for some anomaly, we've been getting null Content fields in the catalog table. For this reason, the API is now "The Final Word" for extracting lineage metadata. However, this code is useful to me - thank you!

Comment: Here's a bit of SQL that should return the embedded as well as shared data sources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776289/query-to-find-list-of-all-ssrs-datasets-across-all-ssrs-reports-on-reportser