# SSMS/SSRS - Get Stored Procedure Name Used by SSRS Dataset From Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I have a query (unfinished) that gets generic SysJob/ReportServer information. The only issue I'm having is trying to retrieve the name of the stored procedure a SSRS report uses. I've tried multiple queries but in my current attempt I tried to get the procedure name from the `sysjobsteps.command` column, unfortunately it only contains the `Subscriptions.SubscriptionID` column, which when tracking back to that table, leads me nowhere as well... Any ideas? Thanks!

```
SELECT JOBS.Name AS [JobName(ID)]
    , CAT.Name AS [CatName] 
    , SCH.SubscriptionID,
    , SUB.LastRunTime
    , STEPS.command -- @eventData = ReportSchedule.SubscriptionID
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs JOBS
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps STEPS ON JOBS.job_id = STEPS.job_id
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule SCH ON JOBS.name = CAST(SCH.ScheduleID AS sysname)
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions SUB ON SCH.SubscriptionID = SUB.SubscriptionID
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog CAT ON SUB.Report_OID = CAT.ItemID
WHERE JOBS.enabled = 1
ORDER BY CAT.Name
```

An example of the data in the "sysjobsteps.command" column:

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='f3296cc8-79e1-4a99-9723-c1880da25a8d'
```

**SOLUTION (messy, but works):**

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), CAT.content)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CHARINDEX('<CommandText>', CAST(CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), CAT.content)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))), 150),
    CHARINDEX('</CommandText>', SUBSTRING(CAST(CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), CAT.content)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    CHARINDEX('<CommandText>', CAST(CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), CAT.content)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))), 150)) - 1),
    '<CommandText>', '') AS ProcName
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get that from the `ReportServer` database. If I recall correctly the details of the report, the executable, is stored in an encrypted format, as a `varbinary`. You could likely inspect the `rpt` files in your project, but it wouldn't be in the same query as above; you would need do use something like PoSh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: [Query to find list of *all* SSRS DataSets across *all* SSRS reports on ReportServer instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776289/query-to-find-list-of-all-ssrs-datasets-across-all-ssrs-reports-on-reportser)

One of its answers has a fairly large and well documented example of how to get shared and embedded data sets.

Comment: Thanks, took a bit of work but this lead me to exactly what I needed!

Comment: if it took more work than the answer provided @haag1 then I think it'd warrant an answer to your own question :) It was a solid question that isn't asked often.