# Find views used in SSRS Reports

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver

I need a query to find the views that are used in the data sets for my SSRS reports. I found couple queries online but I'm facing with this error all the time I run them:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 3, illegal xml character.

I have the view names that I need look for. I just want to see if anyone used these views while they are creating the reports.

Comment: Show us the query giving you the error and we may be able to fix the query for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to find list of \*all\* SSRS DataSets across \*all\* SSRS reports on ReportServer instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776289/query-to-find-list-of-all-ssrs-datasets-across-all-ssrs-reports-on-reportser)

Comment: The duplicate shows you how to get the dataset SQL and since you have the view names just see if they occur in the dataset SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL Server Profiler to monitor all of traffic in and out of your database. This can tell you which views, tables and SQL statements are being used when the SSRS reports are run.

Here are instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/create-a-trace-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: But if a report is only run annually (for example) you'll be waiting a year to find them all.

Comment: In that case you can use a development environment or a test/UAT environment to find them all. By the way, it is a best practice to run diagnostics in an environment other than production.